# OwinHost.exe from command line - how to make it start on a different port?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, katana, owin-middleware

Yes, I have looked on google for this seeming simple question w/o much luck.

So my project includes the OwinHost (OwinHost.exe) NuGet package, and this has updated my project in such a way as to allow the Visual Studio IDE, via property pages, to specifically launch OwinHost.exe using whatever url:port I've specified on the 'Web' tab.. .. but since this is currently error-ing out and closing the cmd window before I can see the error.. I thought I'd try to run OwinHost.exe manually...

I know how to `cd` to my web project's `bin` folder and then call out to the appropriate packages subdir to `OwinHost.exe` to make it start listening for web requests. But, it listens on port `:5000` and I want to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh.. just figured it out...  the `-u` switch..

`..\..\packages\OwinHost.3.1.0\tools\OwinHost.exe -u https://localhost:443/`